# Excel VBA File not Found although file exists

Tags: excel, vba

I have written below piece of code to access a file and copy content from one file to the other. I am using excel 2007.

```
Sub copypaste()

  Dim strFolder As String
  Dim strFileName As String
  Dim wb As Workbook
  strFolder = "C:\Users\user\Desktop\sample\"
  strFileName = Dir(strFolder & "*.xlsx")
  Dim eRow
  Dim a As Variant
  Dim b As Variant
  Do While Len(strFileName) > 0
  **Set wb = Workbooks.Open(strFileName)**
  a = Cells(7, 7)
  b = Range("D11:F11")
  ActiveWorkbook.Close
      Worksheets("sheet1").Cells(7, 7) = a
      Worksheets("sheet1").Cells(7, 8) = b
      strFileName = Dir
  Loop
End Sub
```

Although the file exists in the folder I get the error while opening the file. While in debug mode the variable strFileName contains the file name but still the file is not opening. I am getting the error at line `"Set wb = Workbooks.Open(strFileName)"`

Thanks in advance for your help!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Workbooks.Open requires the full path to the workbook.  I suspect you want:

```
Set wb = Workbooks.Open(strFolder & strFileName)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to replace all \ by double \\ in your path

Or add @ in front of you string.

It is cause \ is the character for escape strings, like \n \s and so on so letter after a \ is transformed. 
Try to print your path, you'll see what append.

EDIT

May also try :

```
FileToOpen = Application.GetOpenFilename _
(Title:="Please choose a Report to Parse", _
FileFilter:="Report Files *.xls (*.xls),");
Set wb2 = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=FileToOpen)
```

Comment: I used this strFolder = "C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\sample\\" but still get the same error

Comment: Try to print your var strfilename and paste it here.

Comment: This is what strfilename contains invoice.xlsx.This is the file name I am trying to open

Comment: Sorry I didnt understand. What do you mean by printing the path.

Answer (score 0):

As (gone) user user496736 stated you need to have a full path

But most of the time your path will be very long and cumbersome to type or you will not know it in advance, so the help of **ActiveWorkbook.Path**

Exemple with readonly just for information

```
Dim Alloc_WB As Workbook

Dim FileStr As String
FileStr = ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\" & "my_file.xlsx"

'workbook should be closed at start of code. Otherwise you get an error msg asking to re-open the Workbook
Set Alloc_WB = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=FileStr, ReadOnly:=True)

'...
'Other actions here...
'...

With Alloc_WB
    .Close
End With
```